# Error with Unix shell script Find and delete based on hours

Tags: shell, unix, delete-file, control-m

I'm trying to delete a folder contents in unix based on the date created using the following statement in a shell script.

`find /mypath -mmin +$((60*24*1)) -exec rm -rf {} \;`

I have configured to run this script from Control M. This deletes the folder however the script ends with the error code 1. How can i avoid getting the error so that my job does not get failed?

`find: '/mypath/Xdb/20170802_001028': No such file or directory
find: '/mypath/Xdb/20170802_001027': No such file or directory
find: '/mypath/Xdb/20170801_142539': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why do you use

```
min +$((60*24*1))
```

use this:

```
find /mypath -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

or this removed directory without checking it is empty or not

```
find /mypath -mtime +7 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

+7 remove older then , -7 removes from today to 7

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from SamOl, if you want to stick with your original command then you can tell the Control-M to accept the string *No such file or directory* as "OK".

To do this simply add an On/Do Action in the last tab of the job def =

```
On Do Actions
Specific statement output    
Statement = *    
Code = *No such file or directory*    
Do = Set job to OK
```

There is a YouTube clip here -    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3S7GdAwjQ8

Comment: Thanks for the help!